# What is the effect of parenthesis when using tuples in discriminated union cases?

Tags: f#, tuples, discriminated-union

The [discriminated union syntax as defined by Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fsharp/language-reference/discriminated-unions) documentation does not include parenthesis. The following definition allows me to use field names in the type definition and is compatible with the syntax in the documentation.

```
type Node<'T> = L of value:'T | N of value:'T * children:Node<'T> list
```

This definition:

```
type Node<'T> = L of value:'T | N of (value:'T * children:Node<'T> list)
```

gives me the error:

```
Anonymous type variables are not permitted in this declaration
```

However, parenthesis are fine if I don't use field names:

```
type Node<'T> = L of 'T | N of ('T * Node<'T> list)
```

Comments [in this change request](https://github.com/fsharp/fslang-suggestions/issues/743) mention differences between the use of parenthesis and not but frankly, the whole discussion went over my head.

I was under the impression that I'm defining a tuple whether or not I use parenthesis, i.e. I'd expect the compiler to treat them as redundant, but there is obviously a difference.
What is it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is just overloaded syntax. The two cases are semantically different despite syntactic similarity.

The confusion comes from the fact that the same syntax is used for defining DU case fields *and* for defining tuple types.

Consider these two types:

```
type A = A of int * string
type B = B of (int * string)
```

Here, constructor `A` doesn't wrap a tuple. Instead, it has two fields - first field of type `int`, second field of type `string`. DU case fields may optionally have names, which is why this works too:

```
type A1 = A1 of x: int * y: string
```

Constructor `B`, on the other hand, *does not* have two fields. It has only *one* field, and the type of that field is `int * string`. And since DU case fields may have names, we can give a name to that single field as well:

```
type B1 = B1 of t: (int * string)
```

---

When constructing values of type `A` or `A1`, you specify all the fields in parens:

```
let a = A (42, "foo")
```

Just like in the type declaration, this looks like a tuple, but it's not. It's two separate fields. And since DU case fields may have names, you can use those names when constructing values. Sometimes it's helpful for not mixing them up or just for code readability:

```
let a1 = A1 (x = 42, y = "foo")
```

In fact, DU case fields always have names, even if you didn't specify them explicitly. When omitted, the compiler will assign names that look like `ItemN` (or just `Item` if there is only one field). And yes, you can use them when constructing values:

```
let a = A (Item1 = 42, Item2 = "foo")
```

When constructing values of `B`, on the other hand, you can't use names for tuple elements, because tuple elements don't have names:

```
let b = B (42, "foo") // works
let b = B (Item1 = 42, Item2 = "foo") // doesn't compile
```

But you can use the name of that single field, which is of type `int * string`:

```
let b = B (Item = (42, "foo"))
let b1 = B1 (t = (42, "foo"))
```

---

It works similarly with pattern matching. Consider the expression:

```
match a with
| A (p, q) -> ...
```

Here again, even though `(p, q)` looks like a tuple, it's not. It is not matching a tuple inside constructor `A`. Instead, it matches two fields of the constructor. Not a single tuple. Two fields.

Similarly to constructing values, you can use field names:

```
match a with
| A1 (x = p, y = q) -> ...
```

Using field names also lets you match partially:

```
match a with
| A1 (x = p) -> ...
```

But when you match on `B`, you have two options:

```
(1) match b with B (x, y) -> ...
(2) match b with B t -> ...
```

The second option works for the same reason as matching `A`: constructor `B` has a single field, and we're matching that field.

The first option works because patterns can be *nested*: we're matching the single field of constructor `B`, and then we're matching individual elements of that field in the same pattern.

And of course, you can use the field name too:

```
match b with B (Item = (x, y)) -> ...
match b1 with B1 (t = (x, y)) -> ...
```

---

Perhaps it's unfortunate that syntax for DU case fields is so similar to the syntax for tuples that it creates so much confusion, but here we are. The bottom line to remember is: *these are not tuples*, it's just a similar syntax.

Comment: brilliant. thanks for the in depth explanation. I don't know why I assumed DU cases were automatically interpreted as tuples. Is there a name for DU case types then? They look like (anonymous) records but the pattern matching syntax is similar to tuples. I thought we have tuples,  records and types (classes) but DU cases appear to add another representation. Anyway, thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Re-reading the github issue, I (think) I understand what is different in the case parenthesis is used.

F# requires a tuple to be pattern matched in terms of all of its components, but parenthesis allows the whole tuple to be matched as a single pattern. That is

Given

```
type DU = DUCase of int * int * int
```

this won't work:

```
let tst1 du =
    match du with
    |DUCase c -> ""
```

but given:

```
type DU = DUCase of (int * int * int)
```

it would.

I'll wait before accepting this as the answer, in case I'm wrong and someone corrects me.

**Update**: I stand corrected now.